# Laravel eloquent orwhere in leftjoin fails

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My eloquent query is not giving me what I expects. When I use orWhere it is put on the end of the query not after the leftjoin.

```
$r = groupofpupil::where('group_id' , '=', '13')
     ->leftjoin('pupils' ,'pupil1_id' , '=', 'pu_id' )
     ->orWhere('pupil0_id', '=', 'pu_id')
     ->leftjoin('users', 'pupils.id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->select('*')
     ->get();
```

the sql query is:

```
SELECT * from groupofpupils
LEFT JOIN pupils on pupil1_id = pu_id
LEFT JOIN users on pupils.id = users.id 
WHERE group_id = 13 
OR pupil0_id = pu_id
```

but I expected this

```
SELECT * from groupofpupils 
LEFT JOIN pupils on pu_id = pupil1_id OR pu_id = pupil0_id 
LEFT JOIN users on pupils.id = users.id 
WHERE group_id = 13
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$r = groupofpupil::leftjoin('pupils', 'pupils.pupil1_id', '=', 'groupofpupils.pu_id')
      ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'pupils.id')
      ->where('groupofpupils.group_id', 13) 
      ->orWhere('pupils.pupil0_id', '=', 'groupofpupils.pu_id') 
      ->get();
```